# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null while running JavaScript in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I got this error while executing my JS code in chrome console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
    at getFollowers (<anonymous>:98:53)
    at <anonymous>:57:7
```

My Function being

```
function getFollowers(){
  var followersDiv = document.querySelector('div[role="presentation"]').querySelector('li').parentElement.children;
  for (var i = 0;i<followersDiv.length;i++){
    var tempUser = followersDiv[i].lastElementChild.children[0].children[1];
    followers.push({
      userID: tempUser.children[0].textContent,
      userName: tempUser.children[1].textContent,
    });
  }
  document.querySelector('[aria-label="Close"]').click();
}
```

The line seems to have missing something here

```
 var tempUser = followersDiv[i].lastElementChild.children[0].children[1];
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I would’n say that the line you’re pointing is missing something. I would say this given line expects things to be here without providing enough guarantees.

One way or another, tempUser is built trying to use something that can be null. In my opinion, your code is quite optimistic : you assume lastElementChild to be nonEmpty, to have a children field which is a non empty array, etc… Each step after "followersDiv[i]" may lead to failure, you did not check the values’ content.

There are two strategies to make your code more robust, IMO :

- Use an external library like lodash to have a more robust code. In particular, you may use _.get and _.isEmpty
- Try to use a more accurate CSS selector in your querySelector as I’m not sure you need to manually browse the DOM if your selector is good enough. This way, you won’t have nodes that don’t fit your expectations.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_type

I tried looking into this but it didn't work out as well